# Google Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I am using the Gantt Chart provided by Google.

I have added a listener to when I click on any of the elements or entity in attempt to return the row/columns data, but it is returning empty,

```
    function selectHandler() {
        var selectedItem = chart.getSelection();
        if (selectedItem) {
            console.log(selectedItem);
        }
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

Here is my attempt on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/30cuaarb/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selection does not seem to work with `google.visualization.GanttChart` component, but you could introduce a custom selection as demonstrated below:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ["gantt"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
    data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

    data.addRows([
      ['2014Spring', 'Spring 2014', 'spring',
       new Date(2014, 2, 22), new Date(2014, 5, 20), null, 100, null],
      ['2014Summer', 'Summer 2014', 'summer',
       new Date(2014, 5, 21), new Date(2014, 8, 20), null, 100, null],
      ['2014Autumn', 'Autumn 2014', 'autumn',
       new Date(2014, 8, 21), new Date(2014, 11, 20), null, 100, null],
      ['2014Winter', 'Winter 2014', 'winter',
       new Date(2014, 11, 21), new Date(2015, 2, 21), null, 100, null],
      ['2015Spring', 'Spring 2015', 'spring',
       new Date(2015, 2, 22), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 50, null],
      ['2015Summer', 'Summer 2015', 'summer',
       new Date(2015, 5, 21), new Date(2015, 8, 20), null, 0, null],
      ['2015Autumn', 'Autumn 2015', 'autumn',
       new Date(2015, 8, 21), new Date(2015, 11, 20), null, 0, null],
      ['2015Winter', 'Winter 2015', 'winter',
       new Date(2015, 11, 21), new Date(2016, 2, 21), null, 0, null],
      ['Football', 'Football Season', 'sports',
       new Date(2014, 8, 4), new Date(2015, 1, 1), null, 100, null],
      ['Baseball', 'Baseball Season', 'sports',
       new Date(2015, 2, 31), new Date(2015, 9, 20), null, 14, null],
      ['Basketball', 'Basketball Season', 'sports',
       new Date(2014, 9, 28), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 86, null],
      ['Hockey', 'Hockey Season', 'sports',
       new Date(2014, 9, 8), new Date(2015, 5, 21), null, 89, null]
    ]);

    var options = {
        height: 400,
        gantt: {
            trackHeight: 30
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GanttChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);


   

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', saveSelection);

    var selectedItem; //custom selector

    function saveSelection(e) {
        selectedItem = { row:e.row,column:null};  //save selected item
    }

    function selectHandler() {
        //console.log(selectedItem);
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = selectedItem.row + " row has been selected"; 
    }


}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['gantt']}]}"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
Result: <span id='result' />
```