# Empty GetSelection() Object in Google Charts' Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I've been learning to use Google Charts for a while and so far, I'm having no problem. However, recently I tried using Gantt Charts and a problem came up. I managed to draw a chart correctly with a data fed by SQL server. However, I want to alert the ID of the selected entity if a chart entity is clicked.

I understand that Google Charts have this getSelection() function and Event Handler. However, when I'm trying to implement that, the array returns empty (just [{}] written in the console). I even used Google Charts' example but it still returns empty array.

Here's the code I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script>
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
      return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
      data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

      data.addRows([
        ['Research', 'Find sources',
         new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 5), null,  100,  null],
        ['Write', 'Write paper',
         null, new Date(2015, 0, 9), daysToMilliseconds(3), 25, 'Research,Outline'],
        ['Cite', 'Create bibliography',
         null, new Date(2015, 0, 7), daysToMilliseconds(1), 20, 'Research'],
        ['Complete', 'Hand in paper',
         null, new Date(2015, 0, 10), daysToMilliseconds(1), 0, 'Cite,Write'],
        ['Outline', 'Outline paper',
         null, new Date(2015, 0, 6), daysToMilliseconds(1), 100, 'Research']
      ]);

      var options = {
        height: 275
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      // When the table is selected, update the orgchart.
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() 
      {
          var obj = chart.getSelection();
          alert(obj[0].column);
      });

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ku7tzex/1/#&togetherjs=cjVlbdFhV3

Does anybody know where I did wrong?

Thanks before!

Comment: It doesn't work, see this --> [Google Gantt Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260401/google-gantt-chart)

Answer (score 0):

This https://jsfiddle.net/hrtgp54r/ resolved the issue for me.

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);    

    function selectHandler(){
        var selections = chart.getSelection();
        if (selections.length == 0)
        {
            alert('Nothing selected');
        }
        else
        {
            var selection = selections[0];
            console.info(selection);
            alert('You selected ' + (selection.row == null ? 'something' : data.getValue(selection.row, 0)));
        }
    };
```